# DynamoDB: getting last record with LSI

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have this java code for getting the last record in a table:

```
Map<String, Condition> _keyCondn = new HashMap<String, Condition>();
_keyCondn.put(HASH_ID, new Condition()
                    .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
                    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(hashId)));

    QueryRequest qr = new QueryRequest();

    if (fltrField != null && fltrAttr != null)
    {
        _keyCondn.put(fltrField, new Condition()
                        .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
                        .withAttributeValueList(fltrAttr));
        if (fltrIndex != null)
            qr.setIndexName(fltrIndex);
    }


    qr.withTableName(tableName)
        .withKeyConditions(_keyCondn)
        .withScanIndexForward(false);

    qr.withConsistentRead(true)
        .withLimit(1);
```

request works fine until I include if statement with LSI. Is there a way to make this work?
Or at least a better solution then "get the last record, scan back until we get the needed value"